# What is a CDI bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am a little bit confused, we call CDI bean to the beans which we inject them using `@Inject` annotation or the beans which we use `@Inject` inside them ?

Comment: did you read some manuals/faq about it?
In what context are you using it?
Did you read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html ?
Are you even aware that this is java-ee because I retagged it.

Comment: I am talking about Jboss Weld

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CDI bean` is a bean managed by `CDI container` (Weld for example).

- If it is `@injected` - it is bean
- If it is may `@injects` something - it is bean too.

Comment: what are injected and injects annotation,
are you using At-sign as a replacement for quotation here?

Answer (score 15):

> **CDI beans** are classes that CDI can instantiate, manage, and inject
>   automatically to satisfy the dependencies of other objects. Almost any
>   Java class can be managed and injected by CDI.

For example, PrintServlet got dependency on a Message instance and have it injected automatically by the CDI runtime.

PrintServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/printservlet")
public class PrintServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject private Message message;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().print(message.get());
    }
}
```

Message.java (**This class is a CDI bean**)

```
@RequestScoped
public class Message {
    @Override
    public String get() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

CDI **does not introduce** a new bean type called a *CDI Bean* with its
own unique component model.

CDI **provides a set** of services that can be *consumed by managed beans and EJBs* that are defined by their existing component models.

So, **CDI is just a Bean** (EJB or Managed Bean) handling CDI lifecycle with scope for *Context* and other old feature *DI* .

Comment: I don't think this is true - afaik there is such a thing as a CDI bean, which is distinct from a fully fledged EJB bean.  A CDI bean for example doesn't automatically get transactionalised (this is something that an EJB gets).

Answer (score 3):

CDI got introduced in Java EE 6 to provide some of the features available earlier to EJB only to all components managed by container. So CDI bean covers Servlets, SOAP web service, RESTful web service, entities, EJBs etc.

> So you can use all these terms interchagebly  :
>
> - CDI bean
> - bean
> - managed bean
> - EJB bean
> - container managed bean etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term `CDI bean` might not be technically correct. **Managed bean**  seems more appropriate.

Though, a possible definition of **CDI bean** could be: Any **managed bean** that was **created and injected as a result of the presence of CDI annotations** on a class or as a result of the prensence of `beans.xml` file inside the archive. A CDI bean itself is not a class but a managed instance of a class.

e.g. take the example below:

```java
public class Logger{}
public class Producer {

    @Produces
    public Logger getLogger() {
        return new Logger();
    }
}
```

`Logger` itself is just a class. It becomes a `managed bean` (`CDI bean`) after it is instantiated by the producer and is bound to a context.

CDI beans can only exist inside a container. The **container** needs to implement  the `CDI` specification. It scans part or all of the classpath for CDI annotations based on which it **creates and manages the corresponding beans.** 
Creating a CDI-enabled container from a standalone application is as easy as this:

```
WeldContainer container = new Weld().initialize();
```